# JFreeChart and printing in swt

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jfreechart

I'm using `JFreeChart` inside of a `ChartPanel` with `SWT_AWT` bridging. What I want to do is use the SWT to handle the printing of the chart. Is there a way to take the `chartpanel` and draw it onto the printer GC from SWT?

```
JFreeChart chart = createXYChart(createDataset(v2, v1));

Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.EMBEDDED);
chart.removeLegend();

//ChartComposite c = new ChartComposite(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.EMBEDDED, chart, true);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(comp);
ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
panel.setMaximumDrawHeight(10000);
panel.setMinimumDrawHeight(0);
panel.setMaximumDrawWidth(10000);
panel.setMinimumDrawWidth(0);
panel.setPopupMenu(null);

frame.add(panel);


Shell shell  = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(shell);

try {
    //PrinterData printerData = Printer.getDefaultPrinterData();
    PrinterData printerData = dialog.open();
    if (printerData != null) {
        Printer printer = new Printer(printerData);
        if (printer.startJob("Text")) {
            GC gc = new GC(printer);

            if (printer.startPage()) {
                gc.drawString("HDSDFSDFSDFSDFDS", 0, 0);
                //WANT TO PRINT CHART SOMEHOW HERE
                printer.endPage();
            }
            gc.dispose();
            printer.endJob();
        }
        printer.dispose();
        System.out.println("Print job done.");
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `SWT_AWT` but I use JFreeChart with SWT (using [ChartComposite](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/jfree/jfreechart-swt/1.0.8a/jfreechart-swt-1.0.8a-javadoc.jar!/org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite.html)), and I can capture a chart into an image with the code below. It may help you :

```
ChartComposite chartComposite = ...;
Image image = new Image(chartComposite.getDisplay(), chartComposite.getBounds());
GC gc = new GC(image);
chartComposite.print(gc);
gc.dispose();
```

Comment: I actually found something like that earlier, but one thing I want to do is scale the chart automatically to a full page without a stretching effect.  I can do this using a ChartPanel, but that's an AWT solution, and I need an SWT solution to integrate into my eclipse RCP application.

Ideally I would like to make a chart behind the scenes, without ever showing it to the user and then print it as a full page to a printer automatically.  It's a program that automatically prints data sets without user interaction.

Comment: @CryptDemon You could create the chart in a new `Shell` with the full size, print it, and then close the `Shell`. The drawback is that the user will briefly see the chart is full size on its screen :-/